How to remove a notification symbol?
I am a noob in Ubuntu system. The following symbol appeared in the Ubuntu Files folder:

That "number 1" in the right superior corner of the folder symbol. The symbol appeared after a problem in which the USB device was freezing.
How do I make it disappear? I have no idea how to do this. Thanks in advance!

Fix the device that you are being alerted to?
